# Travis-CI only deploy once after all builds finish

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to write a basic Travis-CI script to test building my Python package and running pytest for Python version 3.5 through 3.8.  Once that has all successfully passed, I then want Travis-CI to build the docs and updated GitHub pages.  I have been able to successfully test building the package and running the tests as expected, and I can even build the docs, but the docs are built 4 times.  I only want the docs to be build and updated once after everything else is successful.  I've read about `Jobs`, but haven't been successful in getting that to work with the `deploy` keyword.

Here is a link to my repo as it is currently: https://github.com/CurtLH/my_pkg

**Here is my existing Travis-CI script that works but deploys to GitHub pages 4 times. How can I adjust the script to only build and deploy the docs once?**

```
language: python
python:
  - 3.8
  - 3.7
  - 3.6
  - 3.5
install:
  - pip install -e .[dev]
script:
  - pytest
  - sphinx-build -n -b html -d docs/build/doctrees docs/source docs/build/html
  - touch docs/build/html/.nojekyll

deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  keep-history: true
  on:
    branch: master
  local_dir: docs/build/html
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split your build into two stages, one with the matrix for the different python versions and another one for the deployment step: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/matrix-expansion/

Then, in your deploy stage, you could build your code for a specific python version and deploy, in which your `.travis.yml` config would become:

```
language: python
python:
  - 3.8
  - 3.7
  - 3.6
  - 3.5
install:
  - pip install -e .[dev]
script:
  - pytest
  - sphinx-build -n -b html -d docs/build/doctrees docs/source docs/build/html
  - touch docs/build/html/.nojekyll

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: deploy
        python: 3.8
        install: pip install -e .[dev]
        script:
          - pytest
          - sphinx-build -n -b html -d docs/build/doctrees docs/source docs/build/html
          - touch docs/build/html/.nojekyll
        deploy:
          provider: pages
          skip_cleanup: true
          github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
          keep-history: true
          on:
          branch: master
          local_dir: docs/build/html
```

You could also use workspaces (in Beta) to store the package version that you want and then fetch it before releasing it to GitHub pages: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/using-workspaces/